# How to write command line (in jenkins) using robocopy to zip one folder?

Tags: jenkins, 7zip, robocopy

How to write command line (in jenkins) using robocopy to zip one folder? 
lets say older then 2 month.

I have jenkins running on windows server (vm), and installed 7zip.

I need to make jenkins run robocopy to archive some folders older then 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `robocopy` is just for copying files. I am assuming you are using Linux Distribution. `find . -mtime +60` with this you can list all the files recursively including sub folders which are older than 2 months. Or else you can use `find .  -type d -mtime +60 -maxdepth=1` to list all the directories only in the current directory. use `-type f` for listing all the files.

This will list all the files and prints on the console.

```
for i in `find .  -type d -mtime +60 -maxdepth 1`; do echo $i; done
```

For you, this will do the trick.

```
for i in `find .  -type d -mtime +60 -maxdepth 1`; do zip -r $i.zip $i; done
```

In the job config, Have a build step `Execute Shell` and copy the code and zip folders will be there. Hope this helps. If any doubts, Please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much, but for now i am not using linux. Jenkins running as a windows service. So i am trying to make step/build to make archive of all "copied" files on the third location.

Comment: Comment if you need any further help.

Comment: If u can help a little bit more, it will be nice :)